# jQuery - How Do I Surround Ajax Loaded Elements in Quotations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a slider of testimonials. The testimonials are pulled from another page on the same site via an ajax .load() method. I am trying to wrap the incoming testimonials in quotations. (ex: This is a testimonial. would be "This is a testimonial."). However, my code isn't working.

This is the function that is supposed to add quotations:

```
function quotations(){
$(this).prepend('"').append('"');
};
```

And here is the ajax function (the testimonial is loaded from /?page=testimonials&gridID=1 .cfgThemeGridGenericContent):

```
$(function($){
$("#slide1").load("/?page=testimonials&gridID=1 .cfgThemeGridGenericContent", function() {shorten('slide1'); quotations();})
};
```

The html structure is as follows:

```
<div class="slides" id="slide1">
This is the testimonial text.
</div>
```

The shorten() function you see is simply a function to make sure the testimonial isn't too long. I have confirmed that it works. If I need to add it, let me know.

Why aren't my testimonials being wrapped in quotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use css:

```
div.slides::before,
div.slides::after {
    content: '"';
}
```

As for "*why didn't it work*" I'd suspect that might depend on what `$(this)` is, within the `quotations()` function.